# Concatenate list of IDs based on matching IDs within a comma separated list in a different column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Using google sheets: 
I've got two columns.

Column A is a list of ID numbers:

N1
N2
N3
N4
N5

Column B is a comma separated list of other ID numbers within column A related to the ID number on that same row:

N2,N3
N3,N4
(null)
(null)
N1

I'm trying to make a formula in a third column, column C, that will display a comma separated list of the ID numbers from column A that match the ID numbers entered entered in Column B.


Intended result:

 A   |    B     | C 
N1 | N2,N3  | N4,N5
N2 | N3,N4  | N1
N3 |  (null)  | N1,N2
N4 |   N1    | N2
N5 |   N1    | (null)


The closest I could get was this formula here:

```
=arrayFormula({concatenate(rept(A:A&",",B:B=A2))})
```

But this will only work if multiple items haven't been entered into column B, so using this only "N4,N5" would be returned in column C rather than the rest shown in the intended result.


Edit(updated Image): I'm now seeing the following, seems there's an error somewhere:
[image: UpdatedImage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 
 {QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B1:B, ","))<>"", "♦"&SPLIT(B1:B, ",")&"♠"&A1:A, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦"))), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "select Col1 offset 1", 0), 
 SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B1:B, ","))<>"", "♦"&SPLIT(B1:B, ",")&"♠"&A1:A, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦"))), "♠"), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0)), 
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B1:B, ","))<>"", "♦"&SPLIT(B1:B, ",")&"♠"&A1:A, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦"))), "♠"), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "limit 0", 1)&",", ))
 ,,999^99))), ",$", ), ", ", ",")}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is amazing -- works exactly as intended. Looks like I was a bit far off from what I needed with my original formula. Could you walk me through how this is working? I thought for sure when I saw the Diamond and Club symbols that there was no way this would work, but I was quite wrong. Looks like those are used as placeholders to identify splits in the string? Why is it necessary to use transpose and query alongside the 999^99 value? Thanks a bunch of taking the time to type that one out.

Comment: yes, you are right... placeholders to identify splits in the string. as for those combos of transpose and query with 999^99. those are for collapsing all cells (all columns and all rows) into one single cell. `=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:B),,999^99))` for collapsing all columns into one single column and the to collapse all rows into one single cell: `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:B),,999^99)),,999^99)`. you may wonder why go extra step and not use shorter stuff like `TEXTJOIN` or `CONCATENATE`, etc. its because all of them are limited to 50k characters while query is limitless

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. Is the formula you created expecting a certain character length for the ID? I notice some oddities if i turn the ID into a longer string (ex: a couple of #N/As pop up if the "N" in N2,N3 is named something a bit longer and concatenated together). Not a big deal, just trying to identify the limitations/expectations put in place because I'm not yet at a level to decipher the whole thing myself :)

Comment: not aware of any. N/A is most likely coz you changed values in B column and not in A column as well (or vice versa)

Comment: Cheers, alright, ill look out for that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @player0, So I keep running into the N/A error and have narrowed down repro steps. EX: Column A has values N1-N9. Column B has values N9 on N8 and N2,N3,N5 on N9. Column C then outputs "#N/A" on rows N2 and N3, but properly displays N9 on row N5 and N8 on N9. I've edited the original post to show what I'm seeing.

Comment: Still showing N/A on my end -- is it working right on yours? Updated image attached to original post

Comment: Awesome, I think that one worked. I'll play around wih it a bit more, but really appreciate the help here